# export powershell cmdlet as executable

Tags: windows, powershell, exe, powershell-cmdlet

Are windows power shell cmd lets stored on the computer as individual files or not.

If so what is the extension of those files.

If not is there a way to export them as individual files?
this would be useful say if I only needed a few cmdlets I could just have them as individual files and invoke them by typing the file name.

Answer (score 1):

Cmdlets cannot be exported as executable commands and moved to other systems.  They require the PowerShell engine in order to operate and are not self-contained.

Answer (score 0):

Cmdlets reside in these DLLs so there is no exe and I don't believe individual Cmdlets can be exported to another system.

> `PS > (Get-Command Write-Host).DLL`
>   `C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility\v4.0_3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility.dll`
>
> `PS > (Get-Command Get-ChildItem).DLL`
>   `C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Management\v4.0_3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Management.dll`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [proxy command](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/03/01/proxy-functions-spice-up-your-powershell-core-cmdlets.aspx) and export this cmdlet as function

Comment: I would think that would only work if PowerShell was still running on the host system. As per Mike Shepard "They are not self contained". So, If PowerShell was running on the host system doing that would be pointless. That article is to get the cmdlets so that they could be manipulated not rendered standalone